# Problem with an integer in Python 3.1

Tags: python, integer, python-3.x

My problem is in line 13(else). I get the error "invalid syntax"

```
Answer = 23
Guess = ()
Gender = input("Are you a boy, a girl or an alien? ")

if Gender == 'boy' or 'Boy':
     print("Nice!", Gender)
if Gender == 'girl' or 'Girl':
     print("Prepare do die!", Gender)
if Gender == 'alien' or 'Alien':
     print("AWESOME my", Gender, "Friend!")   
 while 'Guess' != Answer:
if Guess < Answer:
     print("Too low! try again")
    else:
        print("too high")
```

Comment: You're missing the part there you actually ask the user for a number. Read up on how to read console input.

Comment: There are actually lots of problems with this script. But what's the exact problem you are looking at?

Comment: Im new to programming so i dont know much about it. But this is supposed to be a guessing game. I get the error(invalid syntax) on "else". im not sure how im supposed to understand that :(

Comment: Fix the indentation on the `print` statement prior to the `else`. It should 3 more spaces. This is to match the indentation of the last `print` statement. Also, watch out for the indentation in the previous lines with `while` and `if`.

Comment: @dan04: an answer to your question is important, we should know whether to welcome our galactic overlords or overladies :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is indentation. The `if` has to line-up with the `else`. You also seem to have a leading space before the `while` which must go.

```
if Guess < Answer:
     print("Too low! try again")
    else:
        print("too high")
```

should be

```
if Guess < Answer:
    print("Too low! try again")
else:
    print("too high")
```

`Gender == 'boy' or 'Boy'` doesn't do what you expect. Since `Boy` evaluates to true, it will be equivalent to just `Gender == 'boy'`. You probably want `Gender == 'boy' or Gender == 'Boy'`, which can be simplified to `Gender.lower() == 'boy'` if you're okay accepting *any* case.

You probably also meant to read in the answer before and in the while loop.

You should also follow the accepted [Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and use lower-case words separated by underscores for your variable names, e.g. `gender` instead of `Gender`. Use `Gender` for class names.

Answer (score 0):

That code has serious problems with using `or` and with the difference between strings and variables. Is this what you want?:

```
Answer = 23
Guess = None
Gender = raw_input("Are you a boy, a girl or an alien? ")

if Gender in ('boy', 'Boy'):
     print("Nice!", Gender)
elif Gender in ('girl', 'Girl'):
     print("Prepare do die! %s" % Gender)
elif Gender in ('alien', 'Alien'):
     print("AWESOME my %s Friend!" % Gender)
while Guess != Answer:
    Guess = raw_input('Guess the number: ')
    try:
       Guess = int(Guess)
    except ValueError:
        print('Not an integer')
        continue
    if Guess == Answer:
        print('Alright!')
        break
    elif Guess < Answer:
        print("Too low! try again")
    else:
        print("too high")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (almost) correct program, with my comments:

```
# The recommended style for Python is to use CamelCase for classes only:
answer = 23 
guess = None # An empty tuple () works to, but this makes more sense.
gender = input("Are you a boy, a girl or an alien? ")

# Using gender.lower() means both 'Boy', 'boy', 'BOY' or 'boY' matches:
if gender.lower() == 'boy':
    print("Nice!", gender)
# Although you can do it like this too:
if gender in ('girl' or 'Girl'):
    print("Prepare do die!", gender)
# But this is *always* true, so it's wrong. I left this bug in intentionally:
if gender == 'alien' or 'Alien': 
    print("AWESOME my", gender, "friend!")

# 'guess' == answer will always be false. Remove the quotes:
while guess != answer:
    # And you forgot to ask for the guess...
    guess = int(input("Guess my age? "))

    # Indentation matters in Python:
    if guess == answer:
        print("Yeah, correct!")
    elif guess < answer:
        print("Too low! try again")
    else:
        print("too high")
```

This results in the following:

```
Are you a boy, a girl or an alien? Why, yes, I am.
AWESOME my Why, yes, I am. friend!
Guess my age? 20
Too low! try again
Guess my age? 30
too high
Guess my age? q
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled-1.py", line 19, in <module>
    guess = int(input("Guess my age? "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'q'
```

As you see, verifying your input is a good idea. :) But that's the next step.